# Extracting a sequence of a whole string (Arduino, C++, indexOf, substring)

Tags: c++, string, arduino, substring, indexof

I would like to extract an **arbitrary part of an entire string** and post it via **Serial.println()**.

The source **problem** I encounter is that the string values (A, B, C) are variables and thus "unknown". It messes with the defined terminators " -" and " END $". I can't find suitable anchor points to fetch the exact part of the string I want. I can, if these string values are not present: "curD = 'Data: String1 A'" vs. "curD = 'String1'". I would like to have only "String1 A", "String2 B" or "String3 C".

The examples A, B, C are either an int, float, or string of variable/random length.

This is what I have so far:

```
  char headComputerData[] = "String1 - "; // test; can be String1 -, String2 - etc, to get the next adjacent string sequence till " -"
  //char headComputerData[] = "Computer Data: "; // the prefix of the data value
  char dashTerminator[] = " -";     // one possible suffix of a value
  char dollarTerminator[] = " END $ ";   // the other possible suffix of a value
  int firstIndexComputerData;     // index into inputStringPC of the first char of the value

  String inputStringPC = "Computer Data: String1 A - String2 B - String3 C END $ ";


      firstIndexComputerData = inputStringPC.indexOf(headComputerData);
      firstIndexComputerData += strlen(headComputerData); // firstIndex is now the index of the char just past the head.
      String compData = inputStringPC.substring// string everything between 
      (
      firstIndexComputerData, //first index
      inputStringPC.indexOf(dashTerminator, firstIndexComputerData) //last index (relative)
      );

      Serial.println(compData);
```

Thanks :)

nolimits

Comment: "_I can't find suitable anchor points to fetch the exact part of the string I want._" - Is that the core of the problem? If so, can't you remove everything not relevant to the question and only leave a short example with that in the program? I'm positive it'll be sorted out quickly in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: Good! Try to make a [mcve] of the problem. Take one simple case you can't solve and hardcode that into an example. In such an example, `Serial.println()` has no place. Just deal with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
"Computer Data: String1 A - String2 B - String3 C END $ "<br>
         0     1       2 3 4       5 6 7       8 9   10
```

Output should be

```
 String1 A
 String2 B
 String3 C
```

If thats correct why not go for the space delimiter -provided that the input is always the same format (see above), so you could filter as follows:

```
uint8_t spaceIndex [11] = {};   // we store 10 values + 0 terminator
String inputStringPC = "Computer Data: String1 A - String2 B - String3 C END $ ";
for (uint8_t i = 0; i<10; i++){  // we read 10 space delimiter indices into an array
       if (i != 0) spaceIndex[i] = inputStringPC.indexOf(' ', spaceIndex[i-1] );
        else spaceIndex[i] = inputStringPC.indexOf(' ');
  }
  // Extract the relevant data as strings (indexStart + 1 / indexEnd - 1)
  String Astring = inputStringPC.substring (spaceIndex[1] + 1, spaceIndex[3] -1);
  String Bstring = inputStringPC.substring (spaceIndex[4] + 1, spaceIndex[6] -1);
  String Cstring = inputStringPC.substring (spaceIndex[7] + 1, spaceIndex[9] -1);
```

This should provide the result if I interpreted your question correctly.
A tip: Get rid of the string class in Arsuino and work with char arrays. The principle stays the same.

Comment: If it helped mark as solved if not give feedback whats missing